# Windows Iot 1709 Language Pack

Tags: c#, uwp, windowsiot

I installed the latest Windows iot 1709 Fall Creator update on my raspberry pi 3 device.  I read that it is now able to support multiple languages for Speech synthetiser.

When I get the languages list in my C# UWP code like this :

```
var voices = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.ToList();
```

I'm not seeing anything else than English.

Do I need to install a language pack or something?  If so where can I get it?  Seems that it still not working for Fr-CA (as it should).

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately this is the wrong place for this type of question. StackOverflow is for programming q&a. Maybe try SuperUser?

Comment: ok then, let me reformulate my question...